# How to pass down event handler as prop in Ag-Grid-React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm not sure if this isn't supported or if I just haven't figured this out yet with [Ag-Grid-React](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-react/issues/49).

**My problem:** I need a button component to be rendered in each cell under a *Delete Row* column that has `onClick` and `label` as props. Upon the button being clicked, I need to dispatch a Redux action that deletes the current row from my table's data.

**Column Defs:**

```
import Button from '../button';
import { deleteRow } from './actions';
import { reactCellRendererFactory } from 'ag-grid-react';

const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Delete Row',
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: reactCellRendererFactory(Button),
    cellRendererParams: {
      onClick: (row) => deleteRow(row.data.id),
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      label: 'Delete',
    },
  }, ...
```

**Button Component:**

```
import React, { PropTypes, PureComponent } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class Button extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    labelColor: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    label: 'Save',
    labelColor: 'white',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <RaisedButton
          backgroundColor={this.props.backgroundColor}
          label={this.props.label}
          labelColor={this.props.labelColor}
          onClick={this.props.onClick}
        />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

The `Button` component does not respond to clicking despite having assigned `onClick` in `cellRendererParams`, though it does have access to `this.props.label` and `this.props.onClick`.

`row` appears to be `undefined`, so what is the best way to get the selected row data in this case for the `onClick` handler?

What is the best way to do this? Thanks for any help you can lend :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the click handlers are not bound to the right receiver. May I propose a few changes, to make it easier to reason about the code:

### The `Button` component

Instead of wiring the click handler directly, try defining an interim handler on the `Button` component:

```
_onButtonClick(){
  this.props.onClick(this.props.rowIndex);
}
```

Wire up the above handler in the `Button` react component like:

```
onClick={this._onButtonClick.bind(this)}
```

### The parent React component

In the `deleteRow` method of the parent React component, you could get the `rowIndex`, and thereby identify the current row (it would be represented in the state I guess)

```
deleteRow(rowIndex) {
  //Perform actual delete of `rowIndex` in `this.state.data`
}
```

Hooking up of `deleteRow` in `columnDefs` would look like:

```
const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Delete Row',
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: reactCellRendererFactory(Button),
    cellRendererParams: {
      onClick: this.deleteRow.bind(this), // <==== Hooking up deleteRow
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      label: 'Delete',
    },
  }, ...
```